# Adding footnotes to columns in Optex

Tags: footnotes, plain-tex, optex

Accorging to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643415/258453), it's possible to add footnotes to columns in Optex.

Although I have a vague idea about what the author has in mind, where/how exactly do I add `\penalty-10013` and `\penalty-10014` and other stuff possibly needed to make footnotes work in columns?

Comment: I am planning to create a variant output routine for OpTeX which supports two-column design. It is not quite easy, we need to solve many sub-problems. I'll start to do it in summer this year. If you need to have a solution sooner you can try to set a bounty points for this here. Maybe somebody else creates a solution. Second weak option: if the two columns environment does not span more pages, you can use `\fnotemark` inside `\begmulti`...`\endmulti` and use `\fnotetext` after `\endmulti`.

Comment: @wipet, thank you so much for all the work. I'm not in a hurry, though. I was just imagining a future issue for a future project.

Comment: I created the macro pair \twocol ...\endtwocol which provides footnotes. See http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#twocol

Comment: @wipet, thank you so much! It will be very useful. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to solve the problem with "column footnotes" in two-column mode for OpTeX. The result is [OpTeX trick 0111 and 0112](https://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#twocol). The design allows to start with full page width typesettig and then to switch to two column mode by `\twocol` and to finish this mode by `\endtwocol`. The `\insert`s work in each column individually, i.e. `\fnote`s and `\topinsert`s. It means that each column behaves like a small page individually. Moreover, user can put a vertical material with full page width at selected pages using `\toppage` macro. The code and more detailed description is available at mentioned web site.

Comment: Awesome! Where could I insert `\_betweencolumns` in this implementation, if I want to add a vertical rule between the comuns?

Comment: The horizontal size of columns is set to .48\hsize, it means that the space between columns is 1-2*.48 = 0.04\hsize. A user can change this part of the macros and add some calculations if the explicit inter-column space should be given by a parameter. Next, the \vrule between columns can be implemented at the line where `\line` is printed: replace `\hfil` by `\hfil\vrule\hfil`, for example.

Comment: You're right; I was using some `depth` measure with was breaking things with `toppage`.